# To abstract over something

Tags: single-word-requests

Context: Research paper

Example:

> In some language-processing models, word knowledge is learned by *abstracting over* stored utterances.

I'd appreciate a synonym for the italicized phrase.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done.

Comment: Please explain what you want the sentence to mean.  (I'm not sure how you can learn anything by summarizing over-stored verbiage.)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "abstract over"; it sounds vaguely like a Hegelian form of "obsess over."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not grasp why this question got down votes.

To me, "abstract over stored utterances" sounds like pretentiously inflated jargon.

"Abstract from" or "generalize from" "remembered or recorded utterances" seems to mean the same thing in standard English.

Offhand, I cannot think of any verb other than "generalize from" that is a close synonym to "abstract from."

Comment: To *abstract over* is a common term in computer science, referring to how a more general pattern subsumes or models specific concrete cases, or otherwise hides details of their internals, so *generalize* (*from*) or maybe *infer* (*from*) seem to be the closest synonyms in this context. E.g., “Some language-processing models infer general word knowledge from stored utterances”.

Comment: @ Purdy "Abstract over" may be a common term in computer science. That is exactly what makes it jargon, and jargon is not necessarily bad. What makes "abstract over" pretentious jargon is that "abstract from" and "generalize from" are standard English forms meaning the same thing so jargon is not needed.